# gzip_decompressor not found in CLion (cpp boost library)

Tags: c++, boost, clion

I tried to decompress gzip file using the sample code from [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/gzip.html#basic_gzip_decompressor)

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    ifstream file("example.txt.gz", ios_base::in | ios_base::binary);
    boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> in;
    in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
    in.push(file);
    boost::iostreams::copy(in, cout);
}
```

I installed boost with `$brew install boost`.
I've included boost library using Live Template in CLion as instructed in [CLion documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/quick-cmake-tutorial.html#d43681e369).
[image]

However, this simple code doesn't work. (Edited the error message)

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::gzip_error> >: gzip error: unspecified iostream_category error
```

I'm suspecting that gzip_decompressor is not recognized somehow.

[image]

Looking for a solution!

Edit:

1) This is CMakeLists.txt file.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(practice_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()

add_executable(practice_cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

if(Boost_FOUND)

    target_link_libraries(practice_cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

endif()
```

2) Also, I tried this command on terminal.

```
c++ -I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.63.0 main.cpp -lboost_iostreams -o main
```

which outputs

```
$ ./main 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::gzip_error> >: gzip error: unspecified iostream_category error
Abort trap: 6
```

3) This is commands_compile.json.

```
[
{
  "directory": "/path/to/practice_cpp",
  "command": "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/c++    -I/usr/local/include  -g   -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /path/to/practice_cpp/main.cpp",
  "file": "/path/to/practice_cpp/main.cpp"
}
]
```

4) $ make VERBOSE=ON

```
$ make VERBOSE=ON
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -H/path/to/practice_cpp -B/path/to/practice_cpp --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /path/to/practice_cpp/CMakeFiles /path/to/practice_cpp/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/depend
cd /path/to/practice_cpp && /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /path/to/practice_cpp /path/to/practice_cpp /path/to/practice_cpp /path/to/practice_cpp /path/to/practice_cpp/CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/build
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `CMakeFiles/practice_cpp.dir/build'.
[100%] Built target practice_cpp
/usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.7.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /path/to/practice_cpp/CMakeFiles 0
```

Comment: What is the _actual_ contents of `CMakeLists.txt`. Programming isn't "The Art Of Taming IDEs". If anything, it's the art of taming a compiler, and the IDE is merely a tool [that can get in the way].

Comment: You have to link `-lboost_iostreams` library. Please show your `cmake` file. If it has `find_package(Boost ...` string then add `iostreams`. For example something like this: `find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)`

Comment: Also, I suspect the platform is OSX? Try passing `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS`  and checking `compile_commands.json`

Comment: @sehe  @JustRufus I've added some edits:D . @sehe yes it's osx. I'm very new to cpp, so I don't know where to pass the command. It doesn't work on terminal. Should I include `set(DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS)` to Makefile.cmake? Sorry for too basic a question. In the meantime, I'll google for it!

Comment: Would be `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON .` e.g.

Comment: @sehe I've added compile_commands.json too!

Comment: (oops - disregard me; compile_commands already says it: it's the compile commands, not the link commands which would be needed. `make VERBOSE=ON` would show more)

Comment: @sehe I've added make VERBOSE=ON result:D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139644/discussion-between-sehe-and-hee-kyung-yoon).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am on a similar configuration (macOS + brew installed boost) so I tested it. The cmake configuration listed in the answer now is Okay.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

project(practice_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)


find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()

add_executable(practice_cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

if(Boost_FOUND)

    target_link_libraries(practice_cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

endif()
```

Problem is, this seems different from the original file posted in the question:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(practice_cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

    set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(practice_cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system iostreams)

if(Boost_FOUND)

    message(STATUS "Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS: ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_LIBRARIES: ${Boost_LIBRARIES}")
    message(STATUS "Boost_VERSION: ${Boost_VERSION}")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

endif()

add_executable(BoostTest main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(practice_cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

When I first saw the problem, the file looked like this. I tested it and got the exact error as is in the problem.

So actually `BoostTest` is (was) the executable and you should add `target_link_libraries(BoostTest ${Boost_LIBRARIES})`.

Comment: Oh, yes I found out the problem and that's why I edited the file. But then, it gave `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::gzip_error> >: gzip error: unspecified iostream_category error
` error. Btw, thanks for pointing this out. I've changed the error message.

Comment: @HeeKyungYoon That's because the file `example.txt.gz` is not in the current working directory (cwd). You can set the cwd in the "run configurations" of CLion.

Comment: oops. that's right. While I was doing Ctrl Z, it accidentally changed to original sample code, which is not example.txt.gz. Thanks for pointing this out!